# Calculating probability with extra knowledge about deck

Tags: probability

Say I separate 10 cards from a standard 52 card deck. If I draw a card from these 10 cards, the probability of drawing a card less than 5 is `16/52`. A friend looks at the remaining 42 cards and names off some of the cards. The friend also looks at the 10 separated cards and names off a few of those cards. He does not tell me the positions of the cards. How does this extra knowledge affect the probability?

For example, the friend tells me there is a 2 in both the remaining 42 cards and the 10 separate cards.

For the first situation (knowledge about cards in the remaining 42), I have come up with this formula:
$$\frac{baseline - known_{target}}{total - known_{total}}$$
Where $known_{target}$ is the number of cards less than 5 that we know about. And $known_{total}$ is the number of cards we know about, regardless of their value. So, for the example above, it would give us:
$$\frac{16 - 1}{52 - 1} = \frac{15}{51}$$

I believe this gives the correct probability, if we know a card is not in the set. I don't know, however, how the second situation (knowledge about cards in the separate 10) affects the probability calculation.

Comment: When you say you know one card is not a $2$, do you mean that you know a specific card is not a $2$, or that at least one of the ten cards is not a $2$?  Note that at least one of the ten will always not be a $2$.  Similarly, when you say one of the cards is a $2$, do you take a $2$ out of the deck, then take $9$ random cards from the remaining $51$ to make the ten?  You need to clearly specify what you mean.

Comment: I know one of the cards is a 2, but I do not know which one. For example, my friend peeks at the cards and tells me one of them is a 2.

Comment: One approach is that you are now drawing from all $10$ card subsets that include at least one $2$.  This would be correct if you redraw if there are no $2$'s.  Another would be that your friend looks through the cards, finds a card $n$ below $5$, and says "there is at least one $n$".  This gives you less information, so the probability will be different.  This is what I mean that you need to define the question better.

Comment: I'm not quite understand the first approach. But, the second one is the one I am considering: "there is at least one *n*". What additional information should I provide?

Comment: One way to specify it is that you draw $10$ cards from the deck, agree with your friend that he will look for $2$'s specifically, and tell you whether there is at least one or none.  If you don't know what number he is looking for before he looks, you need to define how he decides what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your friend looks at the $10$ cards and reports whether or not there is at least one $2$ (where the value $2$ is known before he looks) you have a random sample of all 10 card hands with/without $2$'s.  If there are no $2$'s, you can imagine that you start with the deck, throw away the four $2$'s, and draw a card.  The chance it is under $5$ is now $\frac {12}{48}.$  To get the chance of a card below $5$ when we are told that there is at least one $2$ we can do the following:
Chance of a card below a $5$ without information about the $2$'s is $\frac {16}{52}=\frac 4{13}$
Chance the $10$ cards do not contain a $2$ is $\frac {{48 \choose 10}}{{52 \choose 10}}=\frac {246}{595}$
Chance the $10$ cards do not contain a $2$ and we get less than $5:  \frac{12}{48}=\frac 14$
Chance the $10$ cards contain at least one $2$ and we get less than $5: \frac 4{13}-\frac{246}{595\cdot 4}=\frac {3161}{15470}\approx .20433$
Chance the $10$ cards contain a $2$ is $1-\frac {246}{595}=\frac {349}{595}$
Chance we get less than $5$ given that there is at least one $2: \frac{\frac {3161}{15470}}{\frac {349}{595}}=\frac{3161}{9074}\approx0.348$

Comment: Okay, I'm still trying to wrap my head around this. How would I calculate "Chance of a card below a 5 knowing there is at least one 2"?